# Implementing an Exponential Moving Average Filter described by a difference equation in CUDA

Tags: math, cuda, filtering, signal-processing, thrust

I'm currently trying to use CUDA to evaluate a difference equation that represents an **exponential moving average filter**. The filter is described by the following difference equation

```
y[n] = y[n-1] * beta + alpha * x[n]
```

where `alpha` and `beta` are constants defined as

```
alpha = (2.0 / (1 + Period))
beta = 1 - alpha
```

How can the above difference equation be manipulated to get the system response for this filter? What would be an efficient way to implement this filter on the GPU?

I am working on a GTX 570.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would propose to manipulate the above difference equation as indicated below and then using CUDA Thrust primitives.

**DIFFERENCE EQUATION MANIPULATION - EXPLICIT FORM OF THE DIFFERENCE EQUATION**

By simple algebra, you can find the following:

```
y[1] = beta * y[0] + alpha * x[1]

y[2] = beta^2 * y[0] + alpha * beta * x[1] + alpha * x[2]

y[3] = beta^3 * y[0] + alpha * beta^2 * x[1] + alpha * beta * x[2] + alpha * x[3]
```

Accordingly, the explicit form is the following:

```
y[n] / beta^n = y[0] + alpha * x[1] / beta + alpha * x[2] / beta^2 + ...
```

**CUDA THRUST IMPLEMENTATION**

You can implement the above explicit form by the following steps:

1. Initialize an input sequence `d_input` to `alpha` except for `d_input[0] = 1.`;
2. Define a vector `d_1_over_beta_to_the_n` equal to `1, 1/beta, 1/beta^2, 1/beta^3, ...`;
3. Multiply elementwise `d_input` by `d_1_over_beta_to_the_n`;
4. Perform an `inclusive_scan` to obtain the sequence of the `y[n] / beta^n`;
5. Divide the above sequence by `1, 1/beta, 1/beta^2, 1/beta^3, ...`.

**EDIT**

The above approach can be recommended for Linear Time-Varying (LTV) systems. For Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) systems, the FFT approach mentioned by Paul can be recommended. I'm providing an example of that approach by using CUDA Thrust and cuFFT in my answer to [FIR filter in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853140/fir-filter-in-cuda/23741721#23741721).

**FULL CODE**

```
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

int main(void)
{
    int N = 20;

    // --- Filter parameters
    double alpha    = 2.7;
    double beta     = -0.3;

    // --- Defining and initializing the input vector on the device
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_input(N,alpha * 1.);
    d_input[0] = d_input[0]/alpha;

    // --- Defining the output vector on the device
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_output(d_input);

    // --- Defining the {1/beta^n} sequence
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_1_over_beta(N,1./beta);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_1_over_beta_to_the_n(N,1./beta);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_n(N);
    thrust::sequence(d_n.begin(), d_n.end());
    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_1_over_beta.begin(), d_1_over_beta.end(), d_1_over_beta_to_the_n.begin(), thrust::multiplies<double>());
    thrust::transform(d_1_over_beta_to_the_n.begin(), d_1_over_beta_to_the_n.end(), d_input.begin(), d_input.begin(), thrust::multiplies<double>());    
    thrust::inclusive_scan(d_input.begin(), d_input.end(), d_output.begin(), thrust::plus<double>());
    thrust::transform(d_output.begin(), d_output.end(), d_1_over_beta_to_the_n.begin(), d_output.begin(), thrust::divides<double>());

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        double val = d_output[i];
        printf("Device vector element number %i equal to %f\n",i,val);
    }

    // --- Defining and initializing the input vector on the host
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_input(N,1.);

    // --- Defining the output vector on the host
    thrust::host_vector<double> h_output(h_input);

    h_output[0] = h_input[0];
    for(int i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        h_output[i] = h_input[i] * alpha + beta * h_output[i-1];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        double val = h_output[i];
        printf("Host vector element number %i equal to %f\n",i,val);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        double val = h_output[i] - d_output[i];
        printf("Difference between host and device vector element number %i equal to %f\n",i,val);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For another approach, you can truncate the exponential moving average window and then compute your filtered signal by doing a convolution between your signal and the windowed exponential.  The convolution can be computed by using the free CUDA FFT library (cuFFT) because, as you may know, the convolution can be expressed as the point-wise multiplication of the two signals in the fourier domain (This is the aptly name Convolution Theorem, which runs with a complexity of O(n log(n)) ).  This type of approach will minimize your CUDA kernel code and run very very quickly, even on a GeForce 570;  Particularly so if you can do all of your computations in single (float) precision.

Comment: +1. I agree that your approach is definitely the best for a Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) system. At [FIR filter in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853140/fir-filter-in-cuda/23741721#23741721) I'm providing an example of using the FFT approach implemented by CUDA Thrust and the cuFFT library for a FIR (Finite Impulse Response) filter. I have edited my post accordingly.